# Java date formatting?

Tags: java, date, formatting

I want to read a date in the format YYYY-MM-DD.

But if I enter date say for example 2008-1-1, I want to read it as 2008-01-01.

Can anybody help me? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 11):

Or use the much better [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/) lib.

```
    DateTime dt = new DateTime();
    System.out.println(dt.toString("yyyy-MM-dd"));

    // The ISO standard format for date is 'yyyy-MM-dd'
    DateTimeFormatter formatter = ISODateTimeFormat.date();
    System.out.println(dt.toString(formatter));
    System.out.println(formatter.print(dt));
```

The Date and Calendar API is awful.

Answer (score 7):

Use [SimpleDateFormat](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

**[Edited]**

[Few sample codes](http://javatechniques.com/blog/dateformat-and-simpledateformat-examples/).

Comment: Just have to be careful of the threading problems with that! I've had the weirdest bugs arise from use of SimpleDateFormat

Answer (score 7):

Adeel's solution is fine if you need to use the built-in Java date/time handling, but personally I'd much rather use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/). When it comes to formats, the principle benefit of Joda Time is that the formatter is stateless, so you can share it between threads safely. Sample code:

```
DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-M-D");
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DD");

DateTime dt = parser.parseDateTime("2008-1-1");
String formatted = formatter.print(dt); // "2008-01-01"
```

Answer (score 3):

```
import java.text.*;

public class Test
{

    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        try
        {
                SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-DD");  
            System.out.println(sdf.parse(args[0]).toString());
        }
                catch(Exception e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

This works OK, no matter if you write as argument "2008-1-1" or "2008-01-01".

Answer (score 1):

## *java.time*

The `java.util` Date-Time API and their formatting API, `SimpleDateFormat` are outdated and error-prone. It is recommended to stop using them completely and switch to the [modern Date-Time API](https://www.oracle.com/technical-resources/articles/java/jf14-Date-Time.html)<sup>*</sup>.

Also, quoted below is a notice from the [home page of **Joda-Time**](https://www.joda.org/joda-time/):

> Note that from Java SE 8 onwards, users are asked to migrate to java.time (JSR-310) - a core part of the JDK which replaces this project.

**Solution using `java.time`, the modern Date-Time API:**

```
import java.time.LocalDate;
import java.time.format.DateTimeFormatter;
import java.util.Locale;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DateTimeFormatter dtfInput = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("u-M-d", Locale.ENGLISH);
        String input = "2008-1-1";
        LocalDate date = LocalDate.parse(input, dtfInput);
        System.out.println(date);
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
2008-01-01
```

[<kbd>ONLINE DEMO</kbd>](https://ideone.com/0ItOoT)

**Notes:**

1. Use `y` (which specifies *year-of-era*) instead of `Y` (which specifies *week-based-year*).
2. Use `d` (which specifies *day-of-month*) instead of `D` (which specifies *day-of-year*).
3. For parsing, a single `u` can cater to both, two-digit and four-digit year representation. Similarly, a single `M` can cater to both one-digit and two-digit months. `DateTimeFormatter` processes other letters in a similar fashion.
4. Here, you can use `y` instead of `u` but [I prefer `u` to `y`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65928023/10819573).
5. You must have noticed that I have not used a `DateTimeFormatter` for the output string. It is because the [`LocalDate#toString`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) already returns the string in the [ISO-8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) format, uuuu-MM-dd (which is also your desired pattern).

Learn more about the modern Date-Time API from **[Trail: Date Time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/index.html)**.

---

<sup>* For any reason, if you have to stick to Java 6 or Java 7, you can use [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) which backports most of the *java.time* functionality to Java 6 & 7. If you are working for an Android project and your Android API level is still not compliant with Java-8, check [Java 8+ APIs available through desugaring](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support-table) and [How to use ThreeTenABP in Android Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38922754/how-to-use-threetenabp-in-android-project).</sup>